# Wrapping elements of varying length X times before overflowing

Tags: html, css, reactjs, flexbox, css-grid

I'm attempting to display a simple list of tags of different lengths that would span over 3 lines before overflowing **horizontally** while being scrollable using React.

The tags contain text, a border, and not much else:

[image: tag flex]

Here's a magnificent drawing to illustrate what I'm trying to render with different amounts of tags:

[image: finest art]

Here's the code I'm currently using, which has the tags overflowing in the wrong direction, vertically:

```css
:root {
    --scpu-bg: #1b1b1b;
    --scpu-border: #3d3d3d;

    --scpu-fg: #ffffff;

    color: var(--scpu-fg);

    font-size: 14px;
}

body {
    background-color: var(--scpu-bg);
}

.tag-chip {
    padding: 1rem;
    border: 1px var(--scpu-border) solid;
}

.tag-cloud {
    overflow-x: scroll;
 }
 
    .tag-list {
        /*display: grid;

        grid: 1fr 1fr 1fr / ;*/

        max-height: 11rem;
        display: flex;
        gap: 0.7rem;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
    }
```

```html
<div class="tag-cloud">
  <div class="tag-list nav-scroll">
    <span class="tag-chip">6000</span><span class="tag-chip">alagadda</span
    ><span class="tag-chip">artifact</span><span class="tag-chip">audio</span
    ><span class="tag-chip">biological</span
    ><span class="tag-chip">blackwood</span><span class="tag-chip">_cc</span
    ><span class="tag-chip">co-authored</span
    ><span class="tag-chip">container</span><span class="tag-chip">d-11424</span
    ><span class="tag-chip">daevite</span
    ><span class="tag-chip">deer-college</span
    ><span class="tag-chip">doctor-light</span
    ><span class="tag-chip">doctor-mcdoctorate</span
    ><span class="tag-chip">entropic</span
    ><span class="tag-chip">esoteric-class</span
    ><span class="tag-chip">ethics-committee</span
    ><span class="tag-chip">faeowynn-wilson</span
    ><span class="tag-chip">global-occult-coalition</span
    ><span class="tag-chip">grand-karcist-ion</span
    ><span class="tag-chip">hanged-king</span
    ><span class="tag-chip">hy-brasil</span
    ><span class="tag-chip">interactive</span
    ><span class="tag-chip">la-rue-macabre</span
    ><span class="tag-chip">_licensebox</span><span class="tag-chip">meta</span
    ><span class="tag-chip">metallic</span
    ><span class="tag-chip">narrative</span
    ><span class="tag-chip">on-guard-43</span
    ><span class="tag-chip">portal</span><span class="tag-chip">religious</span
    ><span class="tag-chip">ritual</span
    ><span class="tag-chip">s&amp;amp;c-plastics</span
    ><span class="tag-chip">scp</span><span class="tag-chip">serpents-hand</span
    ><span class="tag-chip">spacetime</span
    ><span class="tag-chip">temporal</span
    ><span class="tag-chip">three-moons-initiative</span
    ><span class="tag-chip">three-portlands</span
    ><span class="tag-chip">wanderers-library</span
    ><span class="tag-chip">weapon</span
    ><span class="tag-chip">wilsons-wildlife</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm currently using `display: flex` coupled with `flex-wrap: wrap` to get as close as possible to what i'm trying to do.

Put it simply, I want the tags to be put on 3 lines max, no matter of much width it would take while having tags keep their own width.

Unfortunately, I only know the height the component is supposed to have, and the wrapping effect isn't meant to work with overflow AFAIK.

> If you already know the height of your component, but not the width, why not use `flex-direction: column` ?

Because then every element is given the same width, making an awkward combination:

[image]

> If you have a set amount of rows, why aren't you using `display: grid` ?

Wouldn't columns suffer from the same problem as above ?

Is there any solution other than splitting my array of tags into 3 sections and rendering them independently ?

Comment: So you want max of 3 rows of tags, and everything else to be hidden? right ?

Comment: Exactly, the rest would overflow to the right while being scrollable @AbinThaha

Comment: Yes, tags are dynamically loaded, their amount is not known before rendering @lupz

Comment: Though there is zero support for it at the time of writing (except experimental), grid masonry lay-out might just allow for this exact behaviour. That is, if the final implementation is able to handle the following mix of CSS: `min-width: 100%; grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr; grid-template-columns: masonry;`. As it stands now, that won't work like you wanted, though, as `grid-auto-flow` is implicitly set to `column` when it is `grid-template-columns` that is set to `masonry`. I tried in FireFox and I cannot override the flow direction after declaring a masonry layout 

Comment: @GustvandeWal I'll happily pick your answer if you have a code example / proposal TC link and a preview of beta browser coverage on this keyword

Comment: Yup, thats exactly what i was looking for, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Masonry_Layout

Comment: @Treycos Does the order in which the tags appear matter? Say you add _one_ tag that triggers the overflow (I'll label tags by their `x:y`, so this one would be `1:4`). OPTION 1: the tag is added to the top row, making it `end:1`. OPTION 2: the tag is added to the end of the _shortest_ row. OPTION 3: tag `1:2` becomes `end:1`, `1:3` becomes `end:2` turning would-be `1:4` into `end:3`. OPTION 4: it doesn't matter *at all* and they can go wherever, as long as the design choice is abided? 1 and 2 prevent any shifting of existing tags. 3 is much like Servesh's answer and 4 is what I'm thinking of.

Comment: @GustvandeWal At this point, it doesnt really matter to me. Ideally, it would be added to the top row until reaching 100% width, then starting a second row, then the third one and then overflow. As for the overflow, it would be great if each overflowing element was added to the shortest row, although it seems impossible as it differs from the behavior it had before

Comment: @GustvandeWal The bounty is about to expire, I'm waiting to give it out in case you have another idea

Comment: I'm on holiday and will give you an answer before the expiration. Be sure to delete these comments later on, because they clutter the page. I will do the same when all is said and done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although support is lacking, `masonry` grids are what you are looking for. It is extremely similar to `columns` layout, but less "plain text" focussed. `columns` are what you would go for when you want a newspaper-like layout, which is what you are requesting, but horizontally. From my experience, it has some really weird quirks, like margins that don't behave normally, as well as visual glitches where box-shadows and outlines get **cut off and moved over to the next column**. [G-Cyrillus](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69288739/3791358)' answer beautifully displays how to use it anyway. All I needed to change, was the spacing inside the list. `columns` has full support, so I've added his implementation as a fallback for when `masonry` isn't supported (it's still being worked on and by the looks of it, will take some time to actually land in browsers. I for one can't wait for this note to be outdated, though).

Now to the answer. As of this moment, if you enable the feature in Firefox, you can actually see the `masonry` grid working in [this Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/GustvandeWal/2L6u9swt/). Here is the CSS that matters:

```
{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: masonry;
}
```

Like noted in the Fiddle, there is one property that *would* make this completely CSS-only — `grid-auto-flow: row;`, but that doesn't work (for now, I hope) because the flow direction of the grid is implicitly set to `column` when you set `grid-template-columns` to `masonry`. It cannot be reverted.

To make the switch from flex to masonry, the script loops over the children to detect the amount of rows present in the flexbox. It does so by checking their offset from the top. If the value makes a switch for a 4th time, it adds the appropriate `grid` class to the list.

From your comment:

> As for the overflow, it would be great if each overflowing element was added to the shortest row, although it seems impossible as it differs from the behavior it had before.

`masonry` actually does this automatically!

Comment: Thank you for your answer, which seems to be the right way of solving this problem once supported by major browsers.

Comment: Unfortunately, real life events caught me up in the last hours I had to give the bounty which ended up automatically attributed

Comment: That is not at all a problem. G-Cyrillus' answer is the current best option and I copied it into my answer anyway. You can always make it up by accepting this answer, though 

Answer (score 5):

Via CSS only, you may try writing-mode and column CSS and finally reset size via min-content/max-content and also max-height:100%;

---

**Mind that once** [Masonry Layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Masonry_Layout) will be widely implemented (only FF at the time of that answer), this answer will be obsolete and [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69194293/wrapping-elements-of-varying-length-x-times-before-overflowing/69288739#69322906) is the one you'll be looking for.

> **Warning:** This feature is only implemented in Firefox, and can be enabled by setting the flag `layout.css.grid-template-masonry-value.enabled` to `true` in `about:config`, in order to allow testing and providing of feedback.

---

Here is the idea in action (feedback about browser's failure is welcome)

```css
:root {
  --scpu-bg: #1b1b1b;
  --scpu-border: #3d3d3d;
  --scpu-fg: #ffffff;
  color: var(--scpu-fg);
  font-size: 14px;
}

body {
  background-color: var(--scpu-bg);
}

.tag-chip {
  padding: 1rem;
  border: 1px var(--scpu-border) solid;
}

.tag-cloud {
  overflow-x: scroll;
  max-height: 11rem;
  padding-bottom: 1.2rem;
  display: flex;
}

.tag-list {
  column-count: 3;
  column-rule-width:0;
  writing-mode: vertical-lr;
  width: max-content;
  height: min-content;
  max-height: 100%;
  padding-right:2px;
}

.tag-chip {
  writing-mode: horizontal-tb;
  margin: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="tag-cloud">
  <div class="tag-list nav-scroll">
    <span class="tag-chip">6000</span><span class="tag-chip">alagadda</span
    ><span class="tag-chip">artifact</span><span class="tag-chip">audio</span
    ><span class="tag-chip">biological</span
    ><span class="tag-chip">blackwood</span><span class="tag-chip">_cc</span
    ><span class="tag-chip">co-authored</span
    ><span class="tag-chip">container</span><span class="tag-chip">d-11424</span
    ><span class="tag-chip">daevite</span
    ><span class="tag-chip">deer-college</span
    ><span class="tag-chip">doctor-light</span
    ><span class="tag-chip">doctor-mcdoctorate</span
    ><span class="tag-chip">entropic</span
    ><span class="tag-chip">esoteric-class</span
    ><span class="tag-chip">ethics-committee</span
    ><span class="tag-chip">faeowynn-wilson</span
    ><span class="tag-chip">global-occult-coalition</span
    ><span class="tag-chip">grand-karcist-ion</span
    ><span class="tag-chip">hanged-king</span
    ><span class="tag-chip">hy-brasil</span
    ><span class="tag-chip">interactive</span
    ><span class="tag-chip">la-rue-macabre</span
    ><span class="tag-chip">_licensebox</span><span class="tag-chip">meta</span
    ><span class="tag-chip">metallic</span
    ><span class="tag-chip">narrative</span
    ><span class="tag-chip">on-guard-43</span
    ><span class="tag-chip">portal</span><span class="tag-chip">religious</span
    ><span class="tag-chip">ritual</span
    ><span class="tag-chip">s&amp;amp;c-plastics</span
    ><span class="tag-chip">scp</span><span class="tag-chip">serpents-hand</span
    ><span class="tag-chip">spacetime</span
    ><span class="tag-chip">temporal</span
    ><span class="tag-chip">three-moons-initiative</span
    ><span class="tag-chip">three-portlands</span
    ><span class="tag-chip">wanderers-library</span
    ><span class="tag-chip">weapon</span
    ><span class="tag-chip">wilsons-wildlife</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Almost perfect! Now just add a bit of JS that checks the validity of using 2 or 1 columns and it's exactly what OP asked for, with a well working no-js implementation.
Note that margins in columns can be a bit wonky, by the way. I don't have spacing to the right of the list.

Comment: thanks for the feed back, i can probably add a padding on right to the tag-list for this. added also a reset on column-rule-width :)

Comment: That's a brilliant approach. Thanks for sharing @G-Cyrillus.

Answer (score 1):

```js
let tag = document.querySelector(".tag-chip");
let font = parseInt(getComputedStyle(tag).getPropertyValue("font-size"));
let gap = parseInt(getComputedStyle(tag).getPropertyValue("margin-right"));

const blocks = document.querySelectorAll(".tag-chip");
widths = [];
blocks.forEach((block) => {
  let width = block.getBoundingClientRect().width;
  widths.push(width + gap);
});
const sum = widths.reduce(function(a, b) {
  return a + b;
}, 0);

finalWidth = Math.ceil(sum / (3 * font) + 5); //change 3 by row required.

let tagList = document.querySelector(".tag-list");
let setWidth = tagList.style.setProperty("--finalWidth", `${finalWidth}rem`);
```

```css
:root {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  --scpu-bg: #1b1b1b;
  --scpu-border: #3d3d3d;
  --scpu-fg: #ffffff;
  --font-400: 16px;
  /*decides 1 rem*/
  --finalWidth: 10rem;
  /*changed by JS*/
  color: var(--scpu-fg);
  font-size: var(--font-400);
}

body {
  background-color: var(--scpu-bg);
  overflow: hidden;
}

.tag-chip {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0.4em 1em;
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
  margin-right: 0.5em;
  border: 1px var(--scpu-border) solid;
}

.tag-cloud {
  width: 95vw;
  overflow-x: auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding: 0.5em;
}

.tag-list {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: var(--finalWidth);
}
```

```html
<div class="tag-cloud">
  <div class="tag-list nav-scroll">
    <span class="tag-chip">6000</span>
    <span class="tag-chip">alagadda</span>
    <span class="tag-chip">artifact</span>
    <span class="tag-chip">audio</span>
    <span class="tag-chip">biological</span>
    <span class="tag-chip">blackwood</span>
    <span class="tag-chip">_cc</span>
    <span class="tag-chip">co-authored</span>
    <span class="tag-chip">container</span>
    <span class="tag-chip">d-11424</span>
    <span class="tag-chip">daevite</span>
    <span class="tag-chip">deer-college</span>
    <span class="tag-chip">doctor-light</span>
    <span class="tag-chip">doctor-mcdoctorate</span>
    <span class="tag-chip">entropic</span>
    <span class="tag-chip">esoteric-class</span>
    <span class="tag-chip">ethics-committee</span>
    <span class="tag-chip">faeowynn-wilson</span>
    <span class="tag-chip">global-occult-coalition</span>
    <span class="tag-chip">grand-karcist-ion</span>
    <span class="tag-chip">hanged-king</span>
    <span class="tag-chip">hy-brasil</span>
    <span class="tag-chip">interactive</span>
    <span class="tag-chip">la-rue-macabre</span>
    <span class="tag-chip">_licensebox</span>
    <span class="tag-chip">meta</span>
    <span class="tag-chip">metallic</span>
    <span class="tag-chip">narrative</span>
    <span class="tag-chip">on-guard-43</span>
    <span class="tag-chip">portal</span>
    <span class="tag-chip">religious</span>
    <span class="tag-chip">ritual</span>
    <span class="tag-chip">s&amp;amp;c-plastics</span>
    <span class="tag-chip">scp</span>
    <span class="tag-chip">serpents-hand</span>
    <span class="tag-chip">spacetime</span>
    <span class="tag-chip">temporal</span>
    <span class="tag-chip">three-moons-initiative</span>
    <span class="tag-chip">three-portlands</span>
    <span class="tag-chip">wanderers-library</span>
    <span class="tag-chip">weapon</span>
    <span class="tag-chip">specialist</span>
    <span class="tag-chip">wilsons-wildlife</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Edited with JS included.

Comment: Implemented using JS in this pen `https://codepen.io/sherloke/pen/jOwZJqr?editors=1111`. This is a dynamic, responsive solution.

Comment: Thank you for the codepen. Just letting you know that for your future answers, you can include working code snippets within your posts just like the other answers

Comment: Thanks, implemented in the snippet format.

Answer (score 1):

I wondered whether using plain static CSS "multi column layout" (generally just the `column-width`) could help solving this task and got results that are quite close to the goal, **with two caveats**.

##### Recap of the task:

- Order matters: first "page" of tags should be filled and visible before next that is out of the view-port.
- Tags should be filled horizontally, wrap at the end of the line of the "page".
- After filling the "page" by given amount of lines, next "page" begins to be filled from the top left.
- **(Caveat 1!)** Either "Rigged" non aligner right edges of tags or (ugly) uneven spacing coming from "justified" text blocks" is no issue.
- When tags fit single line, no empty unused vertical space is reserved. (Not in OP's requirement.)

Surprisingly for me, this is all possible, and as I've learnt in the process it's quite what columns are for: biggest surprise was column width rounding.

**Caveat 2** I've found is that in certain situations Blink erroneously tries to balance second-to-last and last column vertically and "borrows" last line from the former and moves it to the later, despite being told to *"fill columns sequentially"* with `column-fill: auto;`. In Firefox no such surprising jumps occurs. I think it's a bug, but haven't investigated further yet.

##### Interactive Demo:

```js
let t, max = 123, c = 0;

onload = () => {
  for (let i = 8; i-- > 0;) addTag();
  t = setInterval(addTag, 500)
}

function addTag() {
  tags.insertAdjacentHTML(
   'beforeend',
   ` <span>${word()}</span>`
  );
  function word() {
    const dict = ['foo', 'fi', 'fa', 'bar',
    'gazonk', 'qux', 'quux'];
    const l = dict.length;
    return dict[Math.floor(Math.random() * l)]
    + '-' + dict[Math.floor(Math.random() * l)];
  };
  c++;
  if (c >= max) clearInterval(t)
}
```

```css
div {
  column-width: 100vw;
  /* This will be rounded to (fraction of) 
     actual container width, so that whole number
     of columns could be viewed together. That is
     exactly what we need in this particular case
     (and probably in general). */
  column-gap: 0; /* Not default apparently. */ 
  column-rule: none; /* Change to see separators. */
  column-count: auto;  /* Default. */
  column-fill: auto;
  /* Not default 
     - this should ensure next column will be
     start filling only after previous is fully
     vertically occupied. 
     Blink does not respect this sometimes: last
     line of second-to-last column occasionaly
     jumps to last columns and back. */
  max-height: 8em; /* No calc for simplicity */
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  text-align: justify;
  /* Personally, I'd rather leave it left-aligned. */
  word-spacing: .5em; /* Larger gaps between tags. */
  counter-reset: tags;
  outline: 1px solid;
}
span {
  display: inline-block;
  outline: 1px solid;
  padding: .2em;
  margin: .3em;
  white-space: nowrap;
  word-spacing: 0; /* Undo gaps. */
}
span::before {
  counter-increment: tags;
  content: counter(tags) ' '
}
.narrow-columns {
  column-width: 40vw;
  /* Again, will be rounded - to half. */
}
.rigged {
  text-align: left;
  word-spacing: 0;
  /* IMHO better. */
}
```

```html
<!--
 Demo controls:
-->
<p>
  <button onclick="clearInterval(t);addTag()">Add Tag</button>
  <button onclick="tags.scrollBy({left:tags.getBoundingClientRect().width,behavior:'smooth'})">Scroll by width →</button>
  <button onclick="tags.scrollBy({left:-tags.getBoundingClientRect().width,behavior:'smooth'})">… ←</button>
|
  <button onclick="clearInterval(t);tags.innerHTML=''">Clear Tags</button>
  <label><input type="checkbox" onchange="tags.classList.toggle('narrow-columns')">Narrower Columns</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" onchange="tags.classList.toggle('rigged')">Rigged</label>
</p>
<div id="tags">
 <!--
  Bunch of 
   <span>foo-bar</span>
  for demonstrative purposes added by JS here.
 -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, I think this is gonna be the best you can do if you are looking for a sole CSS only solution. All the tags keep their own width but they have spacing between them to keep it in the flex flow direction. I think `align-items: center;` looks better than `align-items: start;` but either works.

```css
:root {
     --scpu-bg: #1b1b1b;
     --scpu-border: #3d3d3d;
     --scpu-fg: #ffffff;
     color: var(--scpu-fg);
     font-size: 14px;
}
 body {
     background-color: var(--scpu-bg);
}
 .tag-chip {
     padding: 1rem;
     border: 1px var(--scpu-border) solid;
}
 .tag-cloud {
     overflow-x: none;
     overflow-y: none;
}
 .tag-list {
     max-height: 15rem;
     display: flex;
     gap: 0.7rem;
     flex-wrap: wrap;
     overflow-x: scroll;
     overflow-y: hidden;
     flex-direction: column;
     align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="tag-cloud">
  <div class="tag-list nav-scroll">
    <span class="tag-chip">6000</span>
    <span class="tag-chip">alagadda</span>
    <span class="tag-chip">artifact</span>
    <span class="tag-chip">audio</span>
    <span class="tag-chip">biological</span>
    <span class="tag-chip">blackwood</span>
    <span class="tag-chip">_cc</span>
    <span class="tag-chip">co-authored</span>
    <span class="tag-chip">container</span>
    <span class="tag-chip">d-11424</span>
    <span class="tag-chip">daevite</span>
    <span class="tag-chip">deer-college</span>
    <span class="tag-chip">doctor-light</span>
    <span class="tag-chip">doctor-mcdoctorate</span>
    <span class="tag-chip">entropic</span>
    <span class="tag-chip">esoteric-class</span>
    <span class="tag-chip">ethics-committee</span>
    <span class="tag-chip">faeowynn-wilson</span>
    <span class="tag-chip">global-occult-coalition</span>
    <span class="tag-chip">grand-karcist-ion</span>
    <span class="tag-chip">hanged-king</span>
    <span class="tag-chip">hy-brasil</span>
    <span class="tag-chip">interactive</span>
    <span class="tag-chip">la-rue-macabre</span>
    <span class="tag-chip">_licensebox</span>
    <span class="tag-chip">meta</span>
    <span class="tag-chip">metallic</span>
    <span class="tag-chip">narrative</span>
    <span class="tag-chip">on-guard-43</span>
    <span class="tag-chip">portal</span>
    <span class="tag-chip">religious</span>
    <span class="tag-chip">ritual</span>
    <span class="tag-chip">s&amp;amp;c-plastics</span>
    <span class="tag-chip">scp</span>
    <span class="tag-chip">serpents-hand</span>
    <span class="tag-chip">spacetime</span>
    <span class="tag-chip">temporal</span>
    <span class="tag-chip">three-moons-initiative</span>
    <span class="tag-chip">three-portlands</span>
    <span class="tag-chip">wanderers-library</span>
    <span class="tag-chip">weapon</span>
    <span class="tag-chip">wilsons-wildlife</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on [Deckerz's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69225041/7724384), I think this is closer to what you want. I used grid instead of flexbox, but note that you could get the same result with their answer by just adding some extra style to `tag-chip` and changing `align-items: center` to `align-items: stretch`.

```css
:root {
     --scpu-bg: #1b1b1b;
     --scpu-border: #3d3d3d;
     --scpu-fg: #ffffff;
     color: var(--scpu-fg);
     font-size: 14px;
}
 body {
     background-color: var(--scpu-bg);
}
.tag-chip {
     display: flex;
     padding: 1rem;
     border: 1px var(--scpu-border) solid;
     min-width: max-content;
     justify-content: center;
}
.tag-cloud {
     overflow-x: none;
     overflow-y: none;
}
.tag-list {
     width: auto;
     display: grid;
     gap: 0.7rem;
     overflow-x: scroll;
     overflow-y: hidden;
     grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, 1fr);
     grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
     grid-auto-flow: column;
}
```

```html
<div class="tag-cloud">
  <div class="tag-list nav-scroll">
    <span class="tag-chip">6000</span>
    <span class="tag-chip">alagadda</span>
    <span class="tag-chip">artifact</span>
    <span class="tag-chip">audio</span>
    <span class="tag-chip">biological</span>
    <span class="tag-chip">blackwood</span>
    <span class="tag-chip">_cc</span>
    <span class="tag-chip">co-authored</span>
    <span class="tag-chip">container</span>
    <span class="tag-chip">d-11424</span>
    <span class="tag-chip">daevite</span>
    <span class="tag-chip">deer-college</span>
    <span class="tag-chip">doctor-light</span>
    <span class="tag-chip">doctor-mcdoctorate</span>
    <span class="tag-chip">entropic</span>
    <span class="tag-chip">esoteric-class</span>
    <span class="tag-chip">ethics-committee</span>
    <span class="tag-chip">faeowynn-wilson</span>
    <span class="tag-chip">global-occult-coalition</span>
    <span class="tag-chip">grand-karcist-ion</span>
    <span class="tag-chip">hanged-king</span>
    <span class="tag-chip">hy-brasil</span>
    <span class="tag-chip">interactive</span>
    <span class="tag-chip">la-rue-macabre</span>
    <span class="tag-chip">_licensebox</span>
    <span class="tag-chip">meta</span>
    <span class="tag-chip">metallic</span>
    <span class="tag-chip">narrative</span>
    <span class="tag-chip">on-guard-43</span>
    <span class="tag-chip">portal</span>
    <span class="tag-chip">religious</span>
    <span class="tag-chip">ritual</span>
    <span class="tag-chip">s&amp;amp;c-plastics</span>
    <span class="tag-chip">scp</span>
    <span class="tag-chip">serpents-hand</span>
    <span class="tag-chip">spacetime</span>
    <span class="tag-chip">temporal</span>
    <span class="tag-chip">three-moons-initiative</span>
    <span class="tag-chip">three-portlands</span>
    <span class="tag-chip">wanderers-library</span>
    <span class="tag-chip">weapon</span>
    <span class="tag-chip">wilsons-wildlife</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: He wants all the blocks to have independent width, isn't it? You could possibly help by reviewing my answer too.

Comment: @ServeshChaturvedi Your solution requires declaring a width for `.tag-list` compatible with the right amount of items. Since the list should be dynamic, it would be harder to find the most suitable value for that width.

Comment: I think a js function which could iterate over the elements with getboundingclientrect for width an sum to get full width plus gap which could then be divided by 3 might be what is required. What do u think?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a script like following

```
   <div class="tag-cloud">
  <div id="elment_flex" class="tag-list nav-scroll">
    <span class="tag-chip">6000</span><span class="tag-chip">alagadda</span
    ><span class="tag-chip">artifact</span><span class="tag-chip">audio</span
    ><span class="tag-chip">biological</span
    ><span class="tag-chip">blackwood</span><span class="tag-chip">_cc</span
    ><span class="tag-chip">co-authored</span
    ><span class="tag-chip">container</span><span class="tag-chip">d-11424</span
    ><span class="tag-chip">daevite</span
    ><span class="tag-chip">deer-college</span
    ><span class="tag-chip">doctor-light</span
    ><span class="tag-chip">doctor-mcdoctorate</span
    ><span class="tag-chip">entropic</span
    ><span class="tag-chip">esoteric-class</span
    ><span class="tag-chip">ethics-committee</span
    ><span class="tag-chip">faeowynn-wilson</span
    ><span class="tag-chip">global-occult-coalition</span
    ><span class="tag-chip">grand-karcist-ion</span
    ><span class="tag-chip">hanged-king</span
    ><span class="tag-chip">hy-brasil</span
    ><span class="tag-chip">interactive</span
    ><span class="tag-chip">la-rue-macabre</span
    ><span class="tag-chip">_licensebox</span><span class="tag-chip">meta</span
    ><span class="tag-chip">metallic</span
    ><span class="tag-chip">narrative</span
    ><span class="tag-chip">on-guard-43</span
    ><span class="tag-chip">portal</span><span class="tag-chip">religious</span
    ><span class="tag-chip">ritual</span
    ><span class="tag-chip">s&amp;amp;c-plastics</span
    ><span class="tag-chip">scp</span><span class="tag-chip">serpents-hand</span
    ><span class="tag-chip">spacetime</span
    ><span class="tag-chip">temporal</span
    ><span class="tag-chip">three-moons-initiative</span
    ><span class="tag-chip">three-portlands</span
    ><span class="tag-chip">wanderers-library</span
    ><span class="tag-chip">weapon</span
    ><span class="tag-chip">wilsons-wildlife</span>
  </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" >
var flex_elm = document.getElementById('elment_flex');

 let clientWidth = Math.max(
  flex_elm.scrollWidth,
  flex_elm.offsetWidth,
  flex_elm.clientWidth
  );
var rem = parseFloat(getComputedStyle(document.documentElement).fontSize);

flex_elm.style.maxWidth = ((clientWidth/3)+rem*1*flex_elm.children.length)+"px";
flex_elm.style.width = ((clientWidth/3)+rem*1*flex_elm.children.length)+"px";


flex_elm.style.flexWrap = 'wrap';


</script>
```

load the page without putting wrap and then set the length depending on the content, then set the 'wrap'.